# How to convert charater string to uniqueidentifier and use Stuff function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I'm using function to generate the result. What am I facing now is I pass the ItemGuid as parameter and currently I am using STUFF to find the ItemCode and concatenate result. However I getting an error said that `Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.`

My current result before using STUFF:
`From Date : 01-01-2021 to 31-03-2021 Item No: IN ('a70014a3-2e00-41f0-9c3e-6fb8c4f2ab60','26dd67c1-fe37-41fa-b8c5-ff033928a291')`

My expected result:
`From Date : 01-01-2021 to 31-03-2021 Item No: IN ('ITM001','ITM021')`

Please see my fiddle. [SQL Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=99a09c74eb7deffd539525f3b6a11b8b)

Parameter used: `SELECT[dbo].[func_ReportCriteria2]('2021-01-01','2021-03-31','''a70014a3-2e00-41f0-9c3e-6fb8c4f2ab60'',''26dd67c1-fe37-41fa-b8c5-ff033928a291''') AS 'RESULT 2'`

```
--using STUFF
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[func_ReportCriteria2] 
(@FromDate DateTime
,@ToDate DateTime
,@Item_List NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CRITERIA NVARCHAR(MAX) 
    DECLARE @sqlCommand NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @ItemResult NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @sqlCommand = ''

    IF(ISNULL(@Item_List,'') != '')
    BEGIN
    --find ItemCode and concatenate based on ItemGuid 
    --error occur here
    SET @ItemResult = STUFF( (SELECT ',' + ItemCode 
                  FROM Item
                  WHERE ItemGuid IN (@Item_List)
                  FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
    
    SET @sqlCommand = 'Item No: IN ('+ @ItemResult +') '
    END

    SET @CRITERIA = 'From Date : ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(19),@FromDate,105) + ' to ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(19),@ToDate,105)
    + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + @sqlCommand

RETURN @CRITERIA
END
```

Comment: With `ItemGuid IN (@Item_List)` the `@ItemList` parameter doesn't get converted to inline code. You'll need to run that through [string_split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) or a similar function to generate a set of values.

Comment: Your question is not fully clear to me but this might help you: (1) if you want to pass a list of values then you should use table-valued parameters instead of string of delimited text. (2) since you use string which include string that is NOT in the format "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" you are getting that error. (3) If you want to split string then you can use STRING_SPLIT for simple case that has specific separator text, or JSON/XML for more complex cases which you need to parse first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if this fit your need:

```
declare @FromDate CHAR(10) ,@ToDate CHAR(10), @Item_List nvarchar(MAX)
select 
    @FromDate  = '2021-01-01',-- make sure to convert the DATE from the table to NVARCHAR using style 120
    @ToDate    = '2021-03-31',-- make sure to convert the DATE from the table to NVARCHAR using style 120
    @Item_List = '''a70014a3-2e00-41f0-9c3e-6fb8c4f2ab60'',''26dd67c1-fe37-41fa-b8c5-ff033928a291'''

------------------ Solution --------------------
-- Important! No reason for scalar function! Use it inline your query directly
SELECT 
    N'From Date : ' + @FromDate + ' to ' + @ToDate + N' Item No: IN (' + STRING_AGG(''''+ItemName+'''',',') + N')' 
FROM Item
WHERE ItemGuid in (
    -- Your string includes quotes which we must clear befor CONVERT to GUIDE
    SELECT REPLACE([value],'''','') FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Item_List, ',')
)
```

Note! concat input text to string might be NOT safe and NOT recommended. It has a potential to SQL Injection!

Note: You probably plan a dynamic query, which will SELECT data from the table using the above string, which you asked to build. In this case, this seems like "XY problem" since you probably do not need to build this string at all. You can use the same approach to split string input and execute a direct SELECT query from your table. If we knew what is your final requested result is, then we could help in this as well, but the approach is the same is above code

Answer (score 0):

Try apply convert itemguid

```
Change WHERE ItemGuid IN (@ItemList)

To WHERE cast(ItemGuid as NVARCHAR(MAX)) IN (@ItemList)
```